# multiple inheritance in Java (representing Liger in Java)

Tags: java, oop

Multiple inheritance is possible in JAVA using interfaces.So can we represent LIGER object in JAVA?
Let me give a small heads up:
The liger is a hybrid cross between a male lion and a tigress.
Properties inherited from TIGER 
1. tiger-like striping pattern (attribute- stripes)

Properties inherited from LION
1. lion-like tawny background (attribute - backgroundColour)
2. tail is more like that of lion (attribute- tail)

Behaviour inherited from TIGER
1. swimming (method- swim())

Behaviour inherited from LION
2. very sociable similar to lions. (method- socialize())

How can this be represented in Java?

Comment: As in most cases when you think about "multiple inheritance", inheritance should probably be replaced by composition here.

Comment: [I found a liger!](http://s96.photobucket.com/user/mwahood/media/ligerM.jpg.html)

Comment: @MichaelDautermann: Great work Michael !!!

Comment: I rather thought Liger was a apt example of multiple inheritance. And to answer your question, yes, interfaces are the way to do it. Define a Tiger interface and a Lion interface, and do **class Liger implements Tiger, Lion { ... }**.  Note that this does have its limitations, so you might be stuck accepting Alex's advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use aggregation, not inheritance. Liger combines behaviour of Tiger and Lion but is neither one nor the other. So, aggregation seems to be better here.

```
class Liger {

private Tiger tiger = new Tiger();
private Lion lion = new Lion();

void swim() { tiger.swim(); }

void socialize() { lion.socialize() ; }

Tail getTail() { return lion.getTail(); }

Skin getSkin() { return tiger.getSkin(); }

}
```

Comment: Couldn't agree more. 99% of cases of multiple inheritance can be solved with composition.

Comment: On the other hand Liger does not really contain 2 animals in itself... If each animal upon creation registers somewhere there could be problems.. Looks like this would be good only if Animal class is stateless.